# Question about multiplication of elements in the associated graded ring and associated graded module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

If $F_{\bullet}R$ is a filtration of a ring $R$, the associated graded ring of $R$ is defined as $$
 \mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}(R):=\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \mathrm{gr}_{i}(R),
$$
where $\mathrm{gr}_{i}(R):=F_{i}R/F_{i-1}R$, and we set $\mathrm{gr}_{0}(R):=F_{0}R$. Multiplication of the elements in the ring $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}(R)$ is defined by $$
 (a+F_{i}R)\cdot (b+F_{j}R):=ab+F_{i+j-1}R.
$$ If $M$ is an $R$-module, we define the associated graded $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}(R)$-module $\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}(M)$ as $$
\mathrm{gr}_{\bullet}(M):=\bigoplus_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathrm{gr}_{j}(M),
$$ where $\mathrm{gr}_{j}(M)=F_{j}M/F_{j-1}$. Here we define multiplication as $$
(a+F_{i}R)\cdot (x+F_{j}M):=ax F_{i+j}M.
$$

Question: Suppose that we're given $F_{m}R \cdot F_{n}R = F_{m+n}R$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$, how can you show that $\mathrm{gr}_{n}(R)\cdot \mathrm{gr}_{m}(R) = \mathrm{gr}_{m+n}(R)$? The problem really is that to show that some $a \in \mathrm{gr}_{m+n}(R)$ is also in $\mathrm{gr}_{m}(R) \cdot \mathrm{gr}_{n}(R)$. I've found that the way multiplication is defined (only it seems for homogeneous elements) isn't that useful and I'm having trouble linking an arbitrary element of $\mathrm{gr}_{m+n}(R)$ with those in $\mathrm{gr}_{m}(R)\cdot \mathrm{gr}_{n}(R)$.

I've run in to a similar problem when trying to prove that if given $F_{m}R \cdot F_{n}M = F_{m+n}M$ for all $m\ge 0$ and $n\ge n_0$ with $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ fixed, then $\mathrm{gr}_{m+n}(M)=\mathrm{gr}_{m}(R)\cdot \mathrm{gr}_{n}(M)$.

Comment: Doesn't the obvious argument just work? By definition, some $a \in \text{gr}_{m+n}(R)$ lifts to an element $\tilde{a} \in F_{m+n}(R)$, and this element lies in $F_m(R) \cdot F_n(R)$ so is a sum of products of elements of $F_m(R)$ and $F_n(R)$; then consider the sum of products of their images in $\text{gr}_m(R)$ and $\text{gr}_n(R)$...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thank you for commenting. I was thinking like that, but was hesistant to write that down because it felt wrong in some way. After your encouragement, if we suppose $\bar{a}\in \mathrm{gr}_{m+n}(R)$ for some $a \in F_{m+n}R$ then we can write $a = \sum_{i=1}^s a_{m_i} b_{n_i}$, where $a_{m_i} \in F_mR$ and $b_{n_i} \in F_nR$ using our assumption. Then because the sum is in $F_mR\cdot F_nR$, it follows that $\bar{a} \in \mathrm{gr}_{m}(R) \cdot \mathrm{gr}_n(R)$. That completes the proof?

Comment: You should say somewhat explicitly that in the final step you conclude by working $\bmod F_{m+n-1}(R)$ (and taking the $a_{m_i}$ and $b_{n_i}$ mod $F_{m-1}(R)$ and $F_{n-1}(R)$ respectively), but yes. It's worth being a bit careful about this because otherwise you might be tempted into believing that there's a ring homomorphism from a filtered ring to its associated graded...

Comment: It's still confusing, however, because what I've shown above is that $\bar{a} \in F_m R \cdot F_n R/ F_{m + n-1}R$, and that's not the same (I think) as $F_mR/F_{m-1}R \cdot F_nR/F_{n-1}R$. I think that's what you're saying in your comment above also, but I'm not really understanding you very well. Can you please explain some more what you mean by "conclude by working..."?

Comment: Hmm, okay, it's worth being careful enough here that I'm just going to write up an answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I wanted to ask you to please do that but felt like I shouldn't bother you so much. An answer explaining how to go about working in $\mod F_{m+n-1}R$ would really help for the sake of my sanity. It's something I've never seen properly explained in textbooks, and because I'm just studying alone, I've no one really to ask but the kind people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's be careful. To save myself some typing I'm going to write $G_n$ instead of $\text{gr}_n$ for the associated graded.

Given some $\overline{a} \in G_{m+n}(R)$, it lifts to some $a \in F_{m+n}(R)$. By assumption it can be written $a = \sum a_m b_n$ where $a_m \in F_m(R), b_n \in F_n(R)$. Now consider the images $\overline{a_m} \in G_m(R), \overline{b_n} \in G_n(R)$ and the corresponding sum of products

$$s = \sum \overline{a_m} \overline{b_n} \in G_{m+n}(R).$$

We have

$$a - s = \overline{\sum a_m b_n} - \sum \overline{a_m} \overline{b_n}$$

so let's consider this difference. $\overline{(-)}$, as an operation $F_k(R) \to G_k(R)$, is at the very least linear, so this reduces to a sum

$$\sum \left( \overline{a_m b_n} - \overline{a_m} \overline{b_n} \right)$$

Now the multiplication $G_m(R) \times G_n(R) \to G_{m+n}(R)$ is defined so that $\overline{a_m b_n} = \overline{a_m} \overline{a_n}$ (this does *not* imply that $\overline{(-)}$ is a ring homomorphism, it matters that we're only considering elements of fixed degrees here) so this sum is a sum of terms equal to zero and hence is zero. So $a = s \in G_m(R) G_n(R)$ as desired. The more general result you want about acting on a filtered module has exactly the same proof.